# WebGL textures from YouTube video frames

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video, glsl, webgl

I'm using the technique described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Animating_textures_in_WebGL) ([code](https://github.com/mdn/webgl-examples/tree/gh-pages/tutorial/sample8), [demo](https://mdn.github.io/webgl-examples/tutorial/sample8/)) for using video frames as WebGL textures, and the simple scene (just showing the image in 2D, rather than a 3D rotating cube) from [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html).

The goal is a Tampermonkey userscript (with WebGL shaders, i.e. video effects) for YouTube.

The canvas is filled grey due to `gl.clearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,1)`. But the next lines of code, which should draw the frame from the video, have no visible effect. What part might be wrong? There are no errors.

I tried to shorten the code before posting, but apparently even simple WebGL scenes require a lot of boilerplate code.

[image]

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         tmp
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=youtube.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {

    // will set to true when video can be copied to texture
    var copyVideo = false;

    const video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

    // immediately after finding the video, create canvas and set its dimensions
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'glcanvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', '300');
    canvas.setAttribute('height', '200');
    canvas.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute;');
    video.parentElement.appendChild(canvas);

    var playing = false;
    var timeupdate = false;

    // Waiting for these 2 events ensures
    // there is data in the video
    video.addEventListener('playing', function() {
        playing = true;
        checkReady();
    }, true);
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        timeupdate = true;
        checkReady();
    }, true);
    function checkReady() {
        if (playing && timeupdate) {
            copyVideo = true;
        }
    }

    // Initialize the GL context
    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

    // Only continue if WebGL is available and working
    if (gl === null) {
        alert("Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it.");
        return;
    }

    // Vertex shader program
    const vsSource = `
attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   // convert the rectangle from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
   vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

   // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
   vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

   // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
   vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

   gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);

   // pass the texCoord to the fragment shader
   // The GPU will interpolate this value between points.
   v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
`;

    // Fragment shader program
    const fsSource = `
precision mediump float;

// our texture
uniform sampler2D u_image;

// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord).bgra;
}
  `;

    // Initialize a shader program, so WebGL knows how to draw our data
    function initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource) {
        const vertexShader = loadShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource);
        const fragmentShader = loadShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource);

        // Create the shader program
        const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

        // If creating the shader program failed, alert
        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            alert('Unable to initialize the shader program: ' + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
            return null;
        }

        return shaderProgram;
    }

    // creates a shader of the given type, uploads the source and compiles it.
    function loadShader(gl, type, source) {
        const shader = gl.createShader(type);

        // Send the source to the shader object
        gl.shaderSource(shader, source);

        // Compile the shader program
        gl.compileShader(shader);

        // See if it compiled successfully
        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            alert('An error occurred compiling the shaders: ' + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            gl.deleteShader(shader);
            return null;
        }

        return shader;
    }

    // Initialize a shader program; this is where all the lighting
    // for the vertices and so forth is established.
    const shaderProgram = initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource);

    // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
    var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_position");
    var texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_texCoord");

    // Create a buffer to put three 2d clip space points in
    var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    // Set a rectangle the same size as the image.
    setRectangle(gl, 0, 0, video.width, video.height);

    // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
    var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
        0.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  0.0,
        0.0,  1.0,
        0.0,  1.0,
        1.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  1.0,
    ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create a texture.
    var texture = initTexture(gl);


    function drawScene() {

        // lookup uniforms
        var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_resolution");

        //webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

        // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

        // Clear the canvas
        gl.clearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,1);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
        gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

        // Turn on the position attribute
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

        // Bind the position buffer.
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

        // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
        var size = 2;          // 2 components per iteration
        var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
        var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
        var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
        var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(
            positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

        // Turn on the texcoord attribute
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);

        // bind the texcoord buffer.
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);

        // Tell the texcoord attribute how to get data out of texcoordBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
        var size = 2;          // 2 components per iteration
        var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
        var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
        var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
        var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(
            texcoordLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

        // set the resolution
        gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

        // Draw the rectangle.
        var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
        var offset = 0;
        var count = 6;
        gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
    }


    function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) {
        var x1 = x;
        var x2 = x + width;
        var y1 = y;
        var y2 = y + height;
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
            x1, y1,
            x2, y1,
            x1, y2,
            x1, y2,
            x2, y1,
            x2, y2,
        ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    }


    var then = 0;

    // Draw the scene repeatedly
    function render(now) {
        now *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds
        const deltaTime = now - then;
        then = now;



        if (copyVideo) {
            updateTexture(gl, texture, video);
        }

        drawScene();

        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(render);


    function initTexture(gl) {
        const texture = gl.createTexture();
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        // Because video has to be download over the internet
        // they might take a moment until it's ready so
        // put a single pixel in the texture so we can
        // use it immediately.
        const level = 0;
        const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
        const width = 1;
        const height = 1;
        const border = 0;
        const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
        const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
        const pixel = new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]);  // opaque blue
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
                      width, height, border, srcFormat, srcType,
                      pixel);

        // Turn off mips and set  wrapping to clamp to edge so it
        // will work regardless of the dimensions of the video.
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

        return texture;
    }


    function updateTexture(gl, texture, video) {
        const level = 0;
        const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
        const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
        const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
                      srcFormat, srcType, video);
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem was correctly pointed out by Atekihcan, you're getting things mixed up with your NDC coordinate calculations, and indeed it's a lot easier to just send them directly. Furthermore you can derive the texture coordinates from those rather easily and thus save the setup of the second buffer.

The second problem is that your events are not firing in the chain you expect them to (at least not for me reloading a playing video and running the script). I believe it should be enough to listen to the `timeupdate` event since the time won't update if the video can't play. The working code:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         tmp
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=youtube.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    // will set to true when video can be copied to texture
    var copyVideo = false;
    const video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

    // immediately after finding the video, create canvas and set its dimensions
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'glcanvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', '300');
    canvas.setAttribute('height', '200');
    canvas.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute;');
    video.parentElement.appendChild(canvas);    
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        copyVideo=true;
    }, true);

    // Initialize the GL context
    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

    // Only continue if WebGL is available and working
    if (gl === null) {
        alert("Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it.");
        return;
    }

    // Vertex shader program
    const vsSource = `
attribute vec2 a_position;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0.0, 1.0);
   v_texCoord = a_position*.5+.5;
   v_texCoord.y = 1.-v_texCoord.y;
}
`;

    // Fragment shader program
    const fsSource = `
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_image;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
}
  `;

    const positionData = new Float32Array([
        -1.0,-1.0,
         1.0,-1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0,
         1.0,-1.0,
         1.0, 1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0
    ]);


    // Initialize a shader program, so WebGL knows how to draw our data
    function initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource) {
        const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, loadShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource));
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, loadShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource));
        gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

        // If creating the shader program failed, alert
        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            alert('Unable to initialize the shader program: ' + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
            return null;
        }

        return shaderProgram;
    }

    // creates a shader of the given type, uploads the source and compiles it.
    function loadShader(gl, type, source) {
        const shader = gl.createShader(type);
        gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
        gl.compileShader(shader);

        // See if it compiled successfully
        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            alert('An error occurred compiling the shaders: ' + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            gl.deleteShader(shader);
            return null;
        }

        return shader;
    }

    // Initialize shader program
    const shaderProgram = initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource);

    // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
    var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_position");
    var textureLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_image");

    // Create a vertex buffer
    var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create texture
    var texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255]));
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    // Initialize rendering
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);

    function drawScene() {
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

        // Turn on the vertex attribute
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        // Draw the rectangle
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    }

    // Draw the scene repeatedly
    function render() {
        if (copyVideo)
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, video);

        drawScene();
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
})();
```

Note: I also changed the texture format to RGB (alpha channel will implicitly be 1), but that's irrelevant.

Comment: Stupid me! Didn't even think that there could be issue with video playing. And went down the rabbit hole of drawing wrong conclusions. Thanks for pointing it out. And good work on deriving texcoord from positions.

Comment: Thank you, this works! :) A small problem is that there's some aliasing, even if I create the canvas with the same width and height as the <video> element. Next, I'll try to find out how to draw some 2D shapes "onto the video" (onto the canvas), and *then* try to deal with the aliasing. If you have any tips for any of those plans, or encourage me to post the next StackOverflow question, let me know.

Comment: @root This is untested on your code but try... **(1)** On the line `gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);` replace that `gl.LINEAR` with `gl.NEAREST` ... **(2)** Also add a next line of: `gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);` ... See if these settings help with aliasing.

Comment: @VC.One the magnification filter will only apply when subsampling the input image which is not the case here as the framebuffer resolution is smaller or equal to the input (also the default already is `NEAREST`). `NEAREST` for the minifcation filter (that is applied when supersampling) results in **worse aliasing** as it's simple point filtering whereas `LINEAR` will bilinearly interpolate the closest four pixels, without mipmaps that's the best *hadware* filtering available (one could do custom filtering via shader), in WebGL1 having mipmaps for non-power-of-two textures is not supported.

Comment: @LJᛃ Good points. However let Asker try my suggestion since it was an unusual and **working fix** for my own aliasing problem on multiple videos. The Asker's posted code is setup similar to mine (I think we learnt from the same guys), so it might get similar benefits too. **PS:** The aliasing was most obvious in full screen mode (_ie_ setting `gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` solved it).

Comment: @VC.One I tried that (and other combinations) a few days ago, but still had aliasing. You can try by running the answer in Tampermonkey on YouTube. Adding effects to YouTube is fun. Cool that you do similar things! :)

Comment: So to get rid of aliasing (to make it look similar to the original scaled video), I'll need WebGL2 and mipmaps (i.e. something like `gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`), or alternatively custom filtering via shader? Or if the rest of my shader is fast enough for high resolutions, maybe I could do `<canvas width="1920" height="1080" style="width:640px;height:480px">` and the browser would do anti-aliased scaling from 1080 to 480 for me.

Answer (score 1):

***Edit: As it has been pointed out, first two sections of this answer are completely wrong.***

TLDR: This might not be feasible without a backend server first fetching the video data.

---

If you check the [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Animating_textures_in_WebGL) you followed, the video object passed to `texImage2D` is actually an MP4 video. However, in your script, the video object you have access to (`document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0]`) is just a DOM object. You don't have the actual video data. And it is not easy to get access to that for YouTube. The YouTube player do not fetch the video data in one shot, rather the YouTube streaming server makes sure to stream chunks of the video. I am not absolutely sure on this, but I think it'll be very difficult to work around this if your goal is to have a real time video effects.
I found some discussion on this ([link1](https://github.com/dontglobalmebro/dontglobalmebro.ruhoh.com/blob/master/posts/displaying-youtube-video-in-webgl.md), [link2](https://forum.shapespark.com/t/youtube-video-as-texture/1674)) which might help.

---

That being said, there are some issues in your code from WebGL perspective. Ideally the code you have should be showing a blue rectangle as that is the texture data you are creating, instead of the initial `glClearColor` color. And after the video starts to play, it should switch to the video texture (which will show as black due to the issue I have explained above).

I think it is due to the way you had setup your position data and doing clip space calculation in the shader. That can be skipped to directly send normalized device coordinate position data. Here is the updated code, with some cleaning up to make it shorter, which behaves as expected:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         tmp
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=youtube.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    // will set to true when video can be copied to texture
    var copyVideo = false;
    const video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

    // immediately after finding the video, create canvas and set its dimensions
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'glcanvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', '300');
    canvas.setAttribute('height', '200');
    canvas.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute;');
    video.parentElement.appendChild(canvas);

    var playing = false;
    var timeupdate = false;

    // Waiting for these 2 events ensures
    // there is data in the video
    video.addEventListener('playing', function() {
        playing = true;
        checkReady();
    }, true);
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        timeupdate = true;
        checkReady();
    }, true);
    function checkReady() {
        if (playing && timeupdate) {
            copyVideo = true;
        }
    }

    // Initialize the GL context
    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

    // Only continue if WebGL is available and working
    if (gl === null) {
        alert("Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it.");
        return;
    }

    // Vertex shader program
    const vsSource = `
attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0.0, 1.0);
   v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
`;

    // Fragment shader program
    const fsSource = `
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_image;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
}
  `;

    const positionData = new Float32Array([
        -1.0,-1.0,
         1.0,-1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0,
         1.0,-1.0,
         1.0, 1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0
    ]);

    const texcoordData = new Float32Array([
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
    ]);

    // Initialize a shader program, so WebGL knows how to draw our data
    function initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource) {
        const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, loadShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource));
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, loadShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource));
        gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

        // If creating the shader program failed, alert
        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            alert('Unable to initialize the shader program: ' + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
            return null;
        }

        return shaderProgram;
    }

    // creates a shader of the given type, uploads the source and compiles it.
    function loadShader(gl, type, source) {
        const shader = gl.createShader(type);
        gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
        gl.compileShader(shader);

        // See if it compiled successfully
        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            alert('An error occurred compiling the shaders: ' + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            gl.deleteShader(shader);
            return null;
        }

        return shader;
    }

    // Initialize shader program
    const shaderProgram = initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource);

    // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
    var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_position");
    var texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_texCoord");
    var textureLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_image");

    // Create a vertex buffer
    var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create texture coordinate buffer
    var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create texture
    var texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]));

    // Initialize rendering
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);

    function drawScene() {
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

        // Turn on the vertex attribute
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        // Turn on the texcoord attribute
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(texcoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        // Draw the rectangle
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    }

    // Draw the scene repeatedly
    function render() {
        if (copyVideo) {
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, video);
        }

        drawScene();
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
})();
```

Comment: +1 for sending NDC directly, -2 because this is just plain false: a) youtube uses a HTML5 player for years now b) every video player in existence streams the data in chunks and finally c) literally the first code snippet at the top of the tutorial shows how to setup a `<video>` element to load the data with.

Comment: I upvoted because a part of this answer possibly helped the other answer, and punishing that with an overall negative score doesn't seem appropriate. Thanks!